# How to load different html file in different language Android environment?

Tags: android, html, image, webview

I have some different language html file for different language environment, and all of those html files contain images. Now I want to show suitable html files with WebView adapt to current language of Android. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give special names for non-English files like `file-de.html` for German and then use the following code:

```
private static String getFileName() {
    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        String name = "file-" + config.locale.getLanguage() + ".html";
        stream = getAssets().open(name);
        return name;
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        return "file.html";
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pixie.This is a good way to solve my problem:) Shall we have any other better way to solve solve it without writing java code,such as the remame the assets folder as "assets-de" and the system can auto known how to adapt to different lanugange?(I known the foler "assets-de" can not work, just a example :)

Comment: I don't know any better way so I use this one in my projects. But you can try to find a better solution. If you succeed in this search, please, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Added a new answer, which should be more precise by providing an example.

Answer (score 0):

You might use "string values" to get Android language dependent HTML file names without using any additional java code and just using getString(). Here's an example for 2 languages:

In file *values/strings.xml*:

```
<string name="html_help_basepage">en_help.html</string>
```

In file *de/strings.xml*:

```
<string name="html_help_basepage">some_german_help.html</string>
```

And so on...

For your Java code (loading from local file in asset folder as in question)

```
helpView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_help);
String adaptedToLanguage = getString(R.string.html_help_basepage)        
helpView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + adaptedToLanguage);
```

No additional Java code is needed. I hope this is helpful and answers the question.